# Thread not really sleeping?

Tags: c#, wpf, thread-sleep

I'm trying to disable a `TextBox` for couple of seconds after the user clicks `Enter`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt1" Width="150" Margin="10" KeyUp="txt1_KeyUp"/>
</StackPanel>   

private void txt1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            txt1.IsEnabled = false;
            Thread.Sleep(2500);
            txt1.IsEnabled = true; //all text is added here
        }
    }
```

If i keep typing when the `Thread` is sleeping, everything i typed pops-up in the `TextBox` when the `Thread` "awakes".

My question is if there's some kind of buffer that stores all raised events while the GUI thread is sleeping?

Comment: You shouldn't really be sleeping the UI thread. Rather disable the textbox and schedule a task to re-enable it later.

Comment: I realize that Sleeping the UI thread is not the right choice, However my question is more about how the `Thread.Sleep` method works.

Comment: You are sleeping the UI thread so the key events for the text you type in will need to wait. Also you will probably find your UI unresponsive in this 2.5 seconds i.e. press enter then try to resize the window. To answer your question not buffered but they will be blocked as they all run on the one thread that you have stop from exectuing.

Comment: @TheKingDave so all events are "waiting" until the Thread awakes, and are than being applied on the application?

Comment: UI's in Windows are inherently single threaded and work using a message pump. Messages are added to the pump's queue and processed using the UI thread. If you block the thread, it can't process the messages until it is awakened again.

Comment: @Yoav See nick response, they are "queued". If you look at my answer you'll see a small change to the way you are doing this will make your UI much more responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better solution:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt1" Width="150" Margin="10" KeyUp="txt1_KeyUp"/>
</StackPanel>   

private void txt1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        txt1.IsEnabled = false;
        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500);
            Action action = () => txt1.IsEnabled = true;
            Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
        });
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

You'll see that when you press enter the box is disabled and you are not sleeping on the UI thread.

If you want other UI elements to know when this is complete you can save t (the thread) into the form and you can query it's state (t.ThreadState) to determine if it has finish.